# Close the process/program automatically in 10 min using C#/VC++?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-c++, process

I have one Windows Service/Application running silently on the PC, when user starts any program , i need to count the time and close it down (program) in 15 Minutes. Even when the user close down the particular program ( say winword.exe) with in 15 min, and reopen it... the program should automatically close on 15 th minute...

Comment: Nothing naughty, I hope?

Comment: Nope... I am writing it for Purpose  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I think you may acheive this
1. Manual polling of applications started using `EnumProcessModules` and terminate them using `TerminateProcess` and
2. Using Dll injection using App_Init registry

I'll talk a little more about number 2. 
When you place your dll name in the following registry value in `AppInit_DLLs` in the following registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`, you can make the dll load with almost every application that launches. You could write a 15 min timer in the dllmain of your injected dll and do exitprocess() when it elapses, eventually taking down the entire process.

Comment: +1, yet another variation would be to hook CreateProcess api call and then start timer if new process the target process.

Comment: @VinayC - hooks are to be used with a lot of caution as they tremendously hit the performance and stability of the system. Not recommended! :)

Comment: Actually the process started by the user, but we need to monitor and check for it and then close...

Comment: Both the above listed methods would work for processes started by users. For the first method you need admin rights to terminate processes, which, if you're running through a services, will automatically be taken care of.